# Javascript column average in HTML table returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to accomplish something which should be relatively simple: averaging a column in an HTML table and displaying the result in a row at the very bottom.

Here is my code:

```
function lead_Res() {
    sumVal=0;
    var table = document.getElementById("lead_table");

    for (var i=1; i < (table.rows.length)-1; i++)
    {
      sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
    }

      document.getElementById("lead_res_num").innerHTML = sumVal;
    }
```

And here is the HTML code in question:

```
    <tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="color:white"<strong>Results</strong>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:white" id="lead_res_num"><input 
     type="number"><strong></strong></td></tr>
```

Here is the table code:

```
  <div class="lead_table">
      <table id="lead_table"style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="3%" id="i_d">ID</th>
    <th width="35%" id="assessment">Assessment</th>
    <th width="17%" id="risk_scale">Risk Scale<br>(1=Low Risk; 5=High Risk)</br></th>
    <th width="5%" id="score">Score</th>
    <th width="35%" id="notes">Explanation/Notes/Proposed Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L1</td>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td Scale 1</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L2</td>
    <td>Question 2</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 2</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L3</td>
    <td>Question 3</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 3</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L4</td>
    <td>Question 4</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 4</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <<td align="center">L5</td>
    <td>Question 5</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 5</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L6</td>
    <td>Question 6</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 6</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L7</td>
    <td>Question 7</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 7</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L8</td>
    <td>Question 8</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 8</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L9</td>
    <td>Question 9</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 9</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L10</td>
    <td>Question 10</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 10</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L11</td>
    <td>Question 12</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 12</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L12</td>
    <td>Question 12</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 12</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L13</td>
    <td>Question 13</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 13</td>
    <td id="ans13"><input type="number" min="1" max="5" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="color:white"><strong>Results</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:white" id="lead_res_num"><strong></strong></td>
  </tr>

  </table>
    </div>
```

I have tested the text insertion, that worked fine, so I do have information displayed where I want it to go.

Unfortunately, when I attempt the sum, the box always displays "NaN". I have tried just pointing to one specific cell with a number, and I still get "NaN".

Comment: Just wanted to add that the column in question is the fourth from the left, and I'm subtracting 1 in the for loop since that is the display line.

Comment: what is the value of `parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML)` in every iteration? if just one is `NaN` then `sumVal` is guaranteed to be NaN

Comment: Can you post the full table? It looks like `table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML` is incorrect.

Comment: We need the rest of the table.

Comment: looks like you are targeting the 4th column in your table with `.cells[3]` but in your html you only show us 2 columns

Comment: I've added the table, thanks very much to everyone for the help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your code gets the `.innerHTML` of the various cells, which is the following string:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5">
```

and then attempts to effectively do this:

```
parseInt('<input type="number" min="1" max="5">');
```

which returns `NaN`.

**You need to extract the values of the the form fields themselves.**

This can be done in a much simpler way than looping over the rows. All you need to do is gather up all the form fields into an array and then you can use the **[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method to get the sum of the values of the fields in the array.

You've also got some HTML syntax to fix. You are missing some `>` characters here and there and have `<<` in one case.

I've set up an answer that gets the sum every time any of the values in the fields is modified in real time with the `input` event. If you want to wait until the user is done making edits to a field (after they leave the field), change `input` to `change`. I've also removed all the duplicate styling of the `number` inputs and created a simple CSS style that applies the same effect to all of them without cluttering up the HTML.

```js
// Get a reference to the output element:
var output = document.getElementById("lead_res_num");

// Gather up all the <input type="number"> elements in the table into an array
var scores = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]"));

// Loop through the field references in the array
scores.forEach(function(score){
  // Set up an input event handler for each <input type=number> field
  score.addEventListener("input", function(){
    // Reduce the values from all the inputs to the sum of all of them:
    var sum = scores.reduce(function(sum, item){
      return sum + +item.value;  // The + in front of item.value implicitly converts the value to a number
    }, 0);
    
    // Output the answer
    output.textContent = sum;
  });
});
```

```css
/* No need to repeat styling information when you can apply it to many elements at once: */
input[type="number"] { text-align:center; }
```

```html
<table id="lead_table"style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="3%" id="i_d">ID</th>
    <th width="35%" id="assessment">Assessment</th>
    <th width="17%" id="risk_scale">Risk Scale<br>(1=Low Risk; 5=High Risk)</th>
    <th width="5%" id="score">Score</th>
    <th width="35%" id="notes">Explanation/Notes/Proposed Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L1</td>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 1</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L2</td>
    <td>Question 2</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 2</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L3</td>
    <td>Question 3</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 3</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L4</td>
    <td>Question 4</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 4</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L5</td>
    <td>Question 5</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 5</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L6</td>
    <td>Question 6</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 6</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L7</td>
    <td>Question 7</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 7</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L8</td>
    <td>Question 8</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 8</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L9</td>
    <td>Question 9</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 9</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L10</td>
    <td>Question 10</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 10</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L11</td>
    <td>Question 12</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 12</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L12</td>
    <td>Question 12</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 12</td>
    <td id="ans"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="center">L13</td>
    <td>Question 13</td>
    <td align="center">Scale 13</td>
    <td id="ans13"><input type="number" min="1" max="5"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="color:white"><strong>Results</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:white"><strong id="lead_res_num"></strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Scott, thank you so much for taking the time to provide this information, this is exactly what I needed, it works excellently! I also appreciate the additional suggestions, I will work those in.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the entire table, but it looks like you're either 1) targeting the wrong column, or 2) the innerHTML cannot be parsed into a number. This can happen if there's another HTML element.

Another note is to use `var` before `sumVal` to ensure it is scoped properly.

And also, you'll want to to target `lead_res_num`'s input's `value`, not the `innerHTML`, so that the input field gets filled in with the `sumVal`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your syntax.

1.) In the for loop:

```
for (var i=1; i < (table.rows.length)-1; i++)
{
  sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);
}
```

the table rows start from 0 so `i` should start from  0 unless you are purposefully skipping the first row.

2.) Here is a working example:

```js
$('#returnSum').click(function() 
{
    var sumVal=0;
    var table = document.getElementById("lead_table");
    
    for (var i=0; i < (table.rows.length); i++) sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);

      document.getElementById("lead_res_num").innerHTML = sumVal;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="lead_table">
<tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td style="color:white; font-weight:bold;">First</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi2</td>
    <td>34</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td style="color:white; font-weight:bold;">Second</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi2</td>
    <td>56</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
<tr style="background-color:#4f81bd;">
    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="color:white; font-weight:bold;">Results</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:white;" id="lead_res_num"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="returnSum" value="click for sum"/>
```

Comment: Please don't post code examples to 3rd party sites as those links can break over time and then your answer won't make sense. Also `<strong>` is **[not deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong)**.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Ok. It makes sense, thanks for the tip. For some reason I remember `<strong>` being deprecated years back. Was it brought back or has it never been deprecated at all?

Comment: Never was deprecated. While `b` is valid, it's use is limited since the spec says to use it when you want to draw attention to something, which is exactly when CSS should be used, so CSS `font-weight:bold` is used for that.

Comment: Oh, strange. Thanks. I will edit my answer for number 2.)

Comment: Should probably reword the answer for #1 as well because, if the OP does, in fact, want to omit the first row, then neither of what you posted are errors.

Comment: The `<strong></strong>` and `align` made me think the OP is not so proficient in web programming. That's why I assumed he might be making a mistake with the first row. I will upvote your answer for correcting me and helping out. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you quite followed what I said. `<strong>` is perfectly correct for this situation because it's the semantic way of saying "this is important". `font-weight:bold` is used anytime you want to format something to make it appear bold (which could include `<strong>` elements and is also the reason that `<b>` doesn't get used much anymore even though it's still valid syntax). There is no reason to advise the OP to remove `<strong>` here.

Comment: Ok, i deleted #2. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your issue is occurring when parsing the value into an integer. To be sure, i would run console.log(sumVal) underneath the parse method, to see what the output is. Most likely it's not parsing it. NaN or Not A number, typically occurs when you try to add a number with a non-number. **"It is the returned value when Math functions fail (Math.sqrt(-1)) or when a function trying to parse a number fails (parseInt("blabla"))"**. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN